# Isometric canvas/SVG HTML 5 images

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I'm seeking some tutorials, how I make canvas or SVG (not sure which) images in an isometric map for a RTS game purpose. The images should only be clickable on the visible part, otherwise the user should be clicking on the background image. It can either be done by auto detecting transparent areas of PNG or from color overlay. I have no idea which is best.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you won’t be changing the perspective of your scene, then I would go with SVG because they are DOM elements (clickable out-of-the-box) and you can limit the click area to the non-transparent part of the element.  A very good SVG library is RaphaelJS.

The canvas is a different kind of animal.  The vectors/rasters you draw on a canvas are not “retained”, meaning unlike SVG, you cannot instruct the box you just drew on the canvas to move.  Instead, you are in charge of redrawing that box where you want it. After you draw everything on your canvas, it is basically becomes a big bitmap.  If your scene’s perspective will be changing, you might need what canvas does best: speed and flexibility.  Using matrix transforms, you can do 2D movement, rotations, scalings and skews.  Since you are in charge of the transformation matrix, you can also simulate 3D movement.  If your users have non-IE browsers, you also have WebGL which is a full 3D imaging system.  With this power comes complexity, so you will probably check out the many game development platforms available for canvas.

With both elements, you can use websockets to do your RTS (of course degrading to long-polling for browsers that don’t support websockets).